# Adding results from query 2 to query 1

Tags: php, arrays

I make two queries and I'd like to add rows from query 2 to query 1.  Also, suppose getResult1() returns no column called "item2"

```
    $result1 = getResult1();
    $result2 = getResult2();

    foreach ($result2 as $res)
    {
            $data = array();
            $data['item1'] = $res->item1;
            $data['item2'] = $res->item2;

            $result1[] = $data; 
    }
```

There error I get here is on line

```
$result1[] = $data
```

and reads

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array
```

I think I get what is happening, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.  The rows are ultimately getting converted to JSON, and I can do that that with an array of arrays.

I've fixed the problem by converting $result1 into an array of arrays.  I do this using a while loop and a fetch_array() call, but is there a quick way to just convert $result1 into an array of arrays instead of a record set?

Or can I just use different syntax on my problem line?

Comment: Isn't it an option to use a join query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `result1` variable is not an array, it's an object, so you cannot set data to it using the ArrayAccess `[]`, you can do the following:

```
$result1 = getResult1();
$result2 = getResult2();

foreach ($result2 as $res)
{
        $result2->item1 = $result1->item1;
        $result2->item2 = $result1->item2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a) No, there is no built-in method to retrieve the results as an array of arrays.

b) Why don't you just retrieve `$result2` as associative arrays? Why do you get them as objects and then copy them into arrays? This is really inefficient. Alternatively, if you prefer objects, store `$result1` as an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

c) If you are running two separate queries simply because one of them will not retrieve a certain column, chances are an outer join can save you all of this trouble. Something like this:

```
SELECT table1.item1, table2.item2
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.foreign_key = table2.id
```

Comment: $result2 is a bit more complex than I've shown you.  It is actually retrieved and then fed into another function that does some work on it; then the result of that is concat'd onto $result1.  It should also be noted again that this is ultimately all converted to JSON.  If I can do that without concat'ing the two objects at all, that would be fine.

Comment: Well then, I think you've solved this yourself. `$result1` must be an array if you want to append more rows to it, whether it's an array of arrays or an array of objects is up to you, but unfortunately built-in functions only allow you to fetch one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Append query? ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html )

```
insert into `destinationRecordset` 
select `foo` as `frazzle`, `bar` as `barizzle`, `baz` as `bazzizzle`
from `sourceRecordset`where `foo` like `mu`
```

Comment: Note that a join query may be more appropriate, depending on how one reads your post.